# Angular dynamic formBuilder input fields lose focus after typing one character

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried everything on StackOverflow similar questions but still I couldn't fix this issue.

I have this method in my component.ts file.

```
private initForm() {
    if (this.form) {
        this.form.patchValue(this.course);

    } else {

        var controlsConfig = {
            duration: [this.course.duration],
            credits: [this.course.credits],
            expires: [],
            comment: [this.course.comment]
        };

        // adding custom fields to course controls
        for (var i = 0; i < this.courseCustomFields.length; i++) {
            controlsConfig[this.courseCustomFields[i].key] = [this.course[this.courseCustomFields[i].key]];
        }

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group(controlsConfig);
    }
```

And I have populated the custom field input fields in my component.html like below.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let courseCustomFieldRow of courseCustomFieldsForFront">
     <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let courseCustomField of courseCustomFieldRow">
         <div class="form-group">
              <label>{{courseCustomField.title}}</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="courseCustomField.key">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

But still it loses focus when I type one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to replicate your issue, below is a stackblitz for the same! try adding track by for the `ngFor` it might stop the lists from re-rendering!

If your issue is not resolved please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated!

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let courseCustomFieldRow of courseCustomFieldsForFront;trackBy:trackByKey">
          <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let courseCustomField of courseCustomFieldRow;trackBy:trackByKey">
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{courseCustomField.title}}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="courseCustomField.key">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form!: FormGroup;
  name = 'Angular';
  course: any = {
    duration: 1,
    credits: 15,
    comments: 'asdf',
  };
  courseCustomFields: any = [
    { key: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
    { key: 'credits', title: 'Credits' },
    { key: 'comment', title: 'Comment' },
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  trackByKey = (index: number, obj: object): number => {
    return index;
  };

  get courseCustomFieldsForFront() {
    return [this.courseCustomFields];
  }

  private initForm() {
    if (this.form) {
      this.form.patchValue(this.course);
    } else {
      const controlsConfig: any = {
        duration: [this.course.duration],
        credits: [this.course.credits],
        expires: [],
        comment: [this.course.comment],
      };

      // adding custom fields to course controls
      for (var i = 0; i < this.courseCustomFields.length; i++) {
        controlsConfig[this.courseCustomFields[i].key] = [
          this.course[this.courseCustomFields[i].key],
        ];
      }
      console.log(controlsConfig);
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group(controlsConfig);
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bzxy26?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 0):

Generally this behavior is because you're iterating over an array and the "input" change the array (so Angular must render it again). This is the reason, e.g. iterate in a FormArray over the formArray.controls, or use trackBy, or use an auxiliar array than not change (e.g. we can create `this.aux=this.array.map((x,index)=>index)` and iterate over "aux" instead of this.array. But I don't know this case in your code :(

Three more ideas:

1. I can not understand this`[` `]` in your code

   ```
      [this.course[this.courseCustomFields[i].key]]
      //it's not? 
      this.course[this.courseCustomFields[i].key]
   ```

   else you're assign an **array**! to the control value (if you have
   an input tag has no sense)
2. **NOT** use "var" else "let" or "const". var create a variable global in your aplication, let

   ```
     var controlsConfig={....}
     //replace by
     const controlsConfig={....} //if the variable don't change inside the function
     let controlsConfig={....} //if the variable change inside the function
   ```
3. It's possible you want to use a FormArray of FormGroups instead of
   an array of FormGroups?